# How to declare in Swift a function parameter that is a property name

Tags: swift, properties, closures

I want to have a class that can access a specified property in another class at runtime. I am guessing it is possible if I pass a closure or a function in as a parameter. For example:

```
class X {

    let pointFunction : (Thing) -> (CGPoint)

    init(pointFunction : (Thing) -> (CGPoint)) {
        self.pointFunction = pointFunction
    }

    func action(#thing : Thing) {
        var p = pointFunction(thing)
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
class func getPosition(thing : Thing) -> CGPoint {
    return thing.whereAmI
}
```

then pass `getPosition` when creating X.

But is there some syntax where I can just pass in `whereAmI` as the function name? Then, in the `action` method I can just do:

```
thing.pointFunction
```

Comment: What is `Thing`? Is it one type or does it need to work with multiple types?

Comment: It will be a fixed type for the class X.

Comment: If you make it NSObject you can use KVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a `Thing->CGPoint`. A function literal is as good as a function there:

```
let x = X(pointFunction: {$0.whereAmI})
```

If you could promise that `whereAmI` were a *method* rather than a property, then you could do some other tricks (see http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/), but it only works with methods. Inexplicably IMO Swift properties are not methods. If they were, you could pass `Thing.whereAmI`.

That said, you'd then have to change your init to take `Thing -> () -> CGPoint`, which is a little more awkward anyway, or you'd have to have two inits like this:

```
init(pointFunction : (Thing) -> (CGPoint)) {
    self.pointFunction = pointFunction
}
convenience init(pointMethod : Thing -> () -> CGPoint) {
    self.init(pointFunction: {pointMethod($0)()})
}
```

So really, the `{$0.whereAmI}` approach is easier to work with in most cases than the curried approach, and exactly what I'd recommend here.

Comment: Almost works, but I get a compiler error on the actual thing.PointFunction call. What should that look like?

Comment: thing.pointFunction(). It's a function. You do have to call it.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your question. `self.pointFunction(thing)`, just like you were doing. You just don't need to create a one-off function for it.